# Wordpress Gallery Links

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress page which is showing gallery that I created by using Wordpress built-in post editor: into it here is its url: http://jalrosh.com/lylescenter/?page_id=8

Now the issue is that when I click on some image its big image opens in a new page and that is disturbing page design.  It should come in the central area but it is appearing on the top of the remaining page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not really programming related and could therefore be closed. Why not check the Wordpress Plugin repository for gallery Plugins that use a Lightbox to keep the image on the same page, or some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that could help you do this. For example http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-2-wordpress-plugin/ I haven't used this plugin, but a wordpress plugin search for "lightbox" came with several options. Try some of them out and see what one you like best.

I haven't tried any of them but supposedly they should take any image and have it viewed via a lightbox (which is the correct term for having the image displayed over the existing page).